# Java webserver blocks connections on PC

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, network-programming

At this point, I am testing a webserver client/host system to be run on my raspberry pi (host) and on my pc (client). The basic idea is that every 5 seconds, the client on my pc sends a message to the host located at "192.168.0.11" at port 7051. It processes it and sends a message back to my pc.
For this I am using the following client code:

```
public static String getData() throws Exception {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        int msg = 71;
        out.write("TEALBEE_CUR:" + msg);
        out.flush();
        String input;
        String data = "";
        while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
            data += input;
        }
        socket.close();
        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem here is that while data-flow is consistent and can run for at least a week; I lost use of other sockets connections on my pc, namely my Kodi remote control (this is media centre which I can control through a socket connection on my smartphone). My pc at address "192.168.0.37" accepts connections at port 193 for Kodi but after running the Java client for some time and sending a lot of requests to the server, I notice that the remote cannot connect anymore to my PC.

I thought that this might be the case because the sockets cannot be reused and after a single use the socket becomes unusable. This does seem to be the case as my host detects a different socket port for each request.
I tried to solve this by adding the code `socket.setReuseAddress(true)` and properly closing the socket after each message, but the problem still occurs.

How can I fix this properly (if possible only use one client socket and close this properly so it can be used again the next time).

EDIT: also important to note I can access 192.168.0.37:193 from my PC, but not from my smartphone when the socket connection cannot be established. Yes I am sure that the PC and smartphone and RPI are on the same network and without the client program running I CAN access 192.168.0.37:193 from my smartphone.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error message or is it failing silently?

Comment: No it just tries to load and after 20-30 seconds or so it states: this page cannot be displayed. I guess it is just a socket timeout?

Comment: The reason I ask is it sounds like your appliance is blocking non-http requests over that port. 20-30 seconds sounds like a timeout. Are you sure that you aren't just unable to hit the server?

Comment: Yes because without the client running I am able to access the Kodi interface without any problems. If my application is blocking non-http requests over that, how could I solve that?

Comment: So this PC what distro\os are you using? Have you tried debugging the android device with adb to see if you can see the response to the socket request?

Comment: If I read this right your kodi is communicating with the PC not the Pi correct?

Comment: Om my pc I am using Windows 10 with the java 8 socket client. My host is on a RPI running rasbian and my smartphone uses android os. My smartphone is not communicating with the rpi but with my PC